# Get all input values from dynamic form in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have some reusable components:

- TextField
- Form

And a component where I import them both. I pass the `TextField` component as props to the `Form`. In this `Form` component I have a submit button which needs to get all the values from the passed `TextField` components. As far as I could read in the docs I could use the `v-model` to get the values. But for some reason I can't find how to get those values in my `Form` component. Maybe I am missing something and I hope someone can help me with it. I already took a look at this question: [Get all Input values - Vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54885894/get-all-input-values-vuejs). However, this didn't solve my problem.

The `TextField` component looks like this:

```
<template>
  <v-text-field
    v-model="vModel"
    :rules="rules"
    :counter="counter"
    :label="label"
    :required="required"
    :placeholder="placeholder"
    :value="value"
  ></v-text-field>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TextField",
  props: {
    rules: Array,
    counter: Number,
    label: String,
    required: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    },
    placeholder: String,
    value: String
  },
  data: () => ({
    vModel: '',
  }),
};
</script>
```

The `Form` component looks like this:

```
<template>
  <v-form>
    <v-container>
      <slot></slot>
      <v-btn class="mr-4" @click="submit">Submit</v-btn>
    </v-container>
  </v-form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    submit () {
      // console.log form data
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

And the component where I import both components:

```
<template>
  <Form>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12" md="4">
          <TextField :label="'Email address'" :vModel="email"/>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
  </Form>
</template>

<script>
import Form from "../../../components/Form/Form";
import TextField from "../../../components/Form/TextField";

export default {
  components: {
    Form,
    TextField,
  },
  data: () => ({
    email: '',
  })
};
</script>
```

I also created a [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-frog-6nf9m?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Can anyone give me some advice on how I might get the `v-model` values from the `TextField` components inside the `Form` component? If it's not possible, or I might do this better in another way please let me know.

Comment: I'm no vuejs/vuetify expert - but the `:vModel="email"` doesn't look like any syntax I've ever seen

Comment: I looked at your sandbox as well. You would have to pass the data as a prop to the form component as well to submit it from there: https://codesandbox.io/s/late-forest-7pd8q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-model` is simply a shorthand to create two things:

- a `:value` binding (passed as a prop to your component)
- a `@input` event handler

Currently, the `vModel` variable in your TextField component may receive the `value`, but it does not send it back to the parent component.

You could try something like this:

TextField

```
<template>
  <v-text-field
    v-model="localValue"
    :rules="rules"
    :counter="counter"
    :label="label"
    :required="required"
    :placeholder="placeholder"
  ></v-text-field>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TextField",
  props: {
    rules: Array,
    counter: Number,
    label: String,
    required: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    },
    placeholder: String,
    value: String
  },
  data: () => ({
    localValue: '',
  }),
  created() {
    this.localValue = this.value;
    this.$watch('localValue', (value) => {
       this.$emit('input', value);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Form

```
<template>
  <v-form>
    <v-container>
      <slot></slot>
      <v-btn class="mr-4" @click="submit">Submit</v-btn>
    </v-container>
  </v-form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['form'],
  methods: {
    submit () {
      alert(JSON.stringify(this.form));
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Your final component:

```
<template>
  <Form :form="form">
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12" md="4">
          <TextField :label="'Email address'" v-model="formvalentin@whatdafox.com"/>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
  </Form>
</template>

<script>
import Form from "../../../components/Form/Form";
import TextField from "../../../components/Form/TextField";

export default {
  components: {
    Form,
    TextField,
  },
  data: () => ({
    form: {
      email: ''
    }
  })
};
</script>
```

> More information on `v-model`: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

Comment: Take a look at the sandbox I created: https://codesandbox.io/s/late-forest-7pd8q. Also, you might want to namespace your form data to pass it around easily: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-kepler-9c40q

Comment: I don't know why but if I copy that code into my own project it alerts `undefined`. I am trying to figure out why but your sandbox works like how I want it to work.

Comment: Make sure you pass the data as props to the form component in your final component. I updated my answer to reflect these changes.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now, completely forgot to pass the data

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure as to what you doing in your code, but to simplify the template and component with v-model would look something like the code below.

ContactUs.vue

```
<template>     
    <form method="POST"
          autocomplete="off"
          class="form--container relative box-col-center w-full"
          name="contact"
          action="/form/contact"
          @submit.prevent="onSubmit">

        <input class="form--field font-poppins w-full"
               type="text"
               name="name"
               v-model="field.name"
               placeholder="Your name"
               autocomplete='name'>

        <input class="form--field font-poppins w-full"
               type="email"
               id="email"
               name="email"
               v-model="field.email"
               placeholder="Your email"
               autocomplete='email'>

        <textarea class="textarea form--field font-poppins w-full"
              id="body"
              name="body"
              placeholder="I'd like to know about ..."
              v-model="field.body"
              rows="5">
            </textarea>

        <button type="submit"
                @click.prevent="onSubmit()"
                class="container--row container--center btn--purple btn--040 w-2/3 lg:w-full">
            <span class="text--w-full uppercase">Submit</span>
        </button>

    </form>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        name: 'ContactUs',
        data() {
            return {
                fields:{
                    name: '',
                    email: '',
                    body: ''
                },
            }
        },
        methods: {
            onSubmit() {
                let vm = this;

                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    axios.post('/forms/contact', vm.fields)
                        .then(response => {
                            resolve(response.data);

                        }).catch(err => {
                            reject(err.response);
                    });
                });
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

If you are attempting to create a Form service class then it would almost the same, except you would abstract the form logic to that class.

FormService.js

```
export default class Form {
    /**
     * Create a new Form instance.
     *
     * @param {object} data
     * @param type
     */
    constructor(data) {
        this.originalData = data;
        for (let field in data) {
            this[field] = data[field];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Submit the form.
     *
     * @param {string} requestType
     * @param {string} url
     */
    submit(requestType, url) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios[requestType](url, this.data())
                .then(response => {
                      resolve(response.data);

                }).catch(err => {
                    reject(err.response);
                });
        });
    }

}
```

and then in your component, you would inject the form services and use the data

ContactUs.vue

```
    import Form from '../services/FormService.js';

    export default {
        name: 'ContactUs',

        data() {
            return {
                fields: new Form({
                    name: '',
                    email: '',
                    body: ''
                }),
            }
        },
        methods: {
            onSubmit() {
                let self = this;

                self.form.post('/forms/contact')
                    .then(response => {


                    }).catch((err) => {

                })
            },
         }
```